# How to pass jQuery variable to div opened by dialog

Tags: jquery, html

I'm working on a user management panel for one of my websites, and I'm trying to figure out how I can properly pass all the correct information to the dialog.

The **HTML** to display the users is this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>{$v.id}</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="editUser" data-userid="{$v.id}">{$v.username}</a></td>
    <td>{if $smarty.now - $v.last_active <= 900}<span style="color: green;">Online</span>{else}<span style="color: #e61e1e;">Offline</span>{/if}</td>
    <td>{$v.email}</td>
    <td>{$v.time}</td>
    <td>{$v.notes}</td>
    <td align="center"><input name="delete" type="checkbox"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When you click the username, it opens a dialog with **jQuery UI**, and this is the **jQuery** code that handles that:

```
   $('a.editUser').click(function(){
        $('#editUser').dialog('open');
        //var userID = $(this).data('userid');
        //var username = $(this).attr('title');
        //$('#editUser').html(userID);
   });
```

Very simple. The commented out code is what I was using just to test to make sure it was differentiating between the users.

Of course, this opens the dialog and works just fine. However, I'm not sure how I can set up the div to properly display the user's information when the dialog opens. Additionally, I'd like to be able to submit changes to the user's account, and I'm not sure how I'd be able to submit the user's ID to the form processor so that it would know which user to modify.

I've been googling around for awhile now, and found many similar threads, but none that really cover this.

Comment: Where is the code for the dialog? Show it first, then I'll see how to help

Comment: @siidheesh http://jqueryui.com/download

Comment: Can you post the code of #editUser html?

Comment: @Afrin, right now it's really just a <div id="editUser">test</div> until I figure out the best way to go about doing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create you #editUser div with

```
<div id="editUser">
<span id="username"></span>
</div>
```

In your function, fill the dialog box with the clicked user's info **before** calling the `dialog` function.

```
$('a.editUser').click(function(){
        $("#username").html($(this).data('userid'));
        $('#editUser').dialog('open');
        //var userID = $(this).data('userid');
        //var username = $(this).attr('title');
        //$('#editUser').html(userID);
   });
```

Now create your form somewhere else with hidden variables. On your submit button, call a javascript function which will extract information from above mentioned ids like $("#username") or JS variables if you use them and set into the form before submitting it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok since dialog `div` is in the same document as the above code, you could just add a div with a known id, for example `<div id="stufftochange"></div>` into the dialog's div.

Then, before you open the div, call `$('#stufftochange').html("user's info here");` to dynamically change its contents, and then `$('#editUser').dialog('open');`